# Httponly cookie not saving in browser with Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cookies, request, httponly

I am using Webstorm to develop an application, and since I'm using JWT authentication, I wanted to use `HttpOnly` cookies to store it in the user's browser. I have made various attempts to make Vuejs work with this, but none seem to work, the cookies just don't appear to be saved in the browser. I've tried simplyfying the controller to just a simple cookie on a GET request, which tested on the browser works fine, but when using with Vuejs it doesn't seem to be stored.

The method is bound as an `@click` to a button stored in one of Vue router's paths:

```js
  methods: {
    async getCookies() {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:8080/test`,
        {
          method: "Get",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          }
        }
      )
    }
```

The response I receive from the server looks like this and works when using it by typing the endpoint in the browser:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCnee.png]

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to find a solution to the issue by doing the following:
First I've changed access on the server side from all origins being able to come through to only the specific port the Vue app is using. Then I set a header as such

```
   credentials: "include"
```

on the request I was sending